# cannot handle custom runtime_error in module

Tags: c++, error-handling, runtime-error

i am trying to handle runtime_error, but compiler says, that ‘runtime_error’ was not declared in this scope. i've already added the "std" namespace. and included the  error.

here is the error:

`In file included from ErrorHandlingModule.cpp:1:
ErrorHandlingModule.h:7:25: error: ‘runtime_error’ was not declared in this scope
  int HandleRuntimeError(runtime_error theRuntimeError);
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
ErrorHandlingModule.cpp:22:54: error: ‘int fpErrorHandling::HandleRuntimeError(std::runtime_error)’ redeclared as different kind of symbol
  int HandleRuntimeError(runtime_error theRuntimeError){`

ErrorHandlingModule.cpp:

```
#include "ErrorHandlingModule.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

namespace fpErrorHandling{
    using namespace std;

    void Initialize(void){
        cin.exceptions(cin.failbit);
    }

    short int HandleNaN_error(void){
        cerr<<"Input error. Not a number?"<<endl;
        cin.clear();

        char BadInput[5];
        cin>>BadInput;

        return 1;
    }

    int HandleRuntimeError(runtime_error theRuntimeError){
        cerr<<theRuntimeError.what()<<endl;

        return 1;
    }

}
```

ErrorHandlingModule.h:

```
#ifndef ErrorHandlingModuleH
#define ErrorHandlingModuleH

namespace fpErrorHandling{
    void Initialize(void);
    short int HandleNaN_error(void);
    int HandleRuntimeError(runtime_error theRuntimeError);
}

#endif
```

Comment: You're missing the header where it's declared: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error

Comment: The `#include` must be in ErrorHandlingModule.h. Then you can remove it from ErrorHandlingModule.cpp if you want to.

Comment: And don't forget the `std::` prefix

Comment: thank you all very much. it worked:)